# Tratar Exceção no Post do Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Tenho esta função `Javascript` (`Post Ajax`) que quando dá exceção no `post` ela está passando no`if (r != "") {`. 
Eu precisava capturar que foi uma exceção e tratá-la fora do `if`.

`JavaScript`

```
function AsyncAlert() {
    $.post("MinhaUrl/AsyncMessage", {}, function (r) {
        if (r != "") {
            mensagemAlert(r);
        }
    });
}
```

`C#`

```
public JsonResult AsyncMessage()
{
    if(TemMensagemNovaAsync())
        return Json(_msgAsync);
    else
        return Json("");
}
```

> Considere que eu preciso capturar a exceção caso não tenha conseguido conectar no backend. Em outras palavras, o servidor da url caiu, a url não estava disponível

Qual a melhor maneira para eu rever isso?

***Observação:*** minha linguagem é `C#`.

Comment: Se manda requisição para qual tipo de linguagem? se quer tratar o que por exemplo, cites problemas?

Comment: Estou utilizando C#

Comment: Bruno pode ser feito um retorno com a excessão que deu no servidor, um paramento indicado `true` ou `false`, é assim nada complicado, mas, ao mesmo tempo fiquei na duvida porque Erros podem ser diversos

Comment: Mas true or false vem no parâmetro "r" no caso? Eu imaginei algo tipo o success do ajax post...

Comment: Bruno eu consigo retornar qualquer coisa pela linguagem de programação, mas, existe uma duvida por exemplo eu consigo retornar assim `r.success = true` sem problemas tranquilamente, mas, está indefinido como você quer que isso seja retornado. Eu posso retornar a execção completa, não sei se é válido para o seu contexto... entendeu?

Comment: Ah sim... entendi o q vc quis dizer. 
Minha preocupação não é no backend, pois lá já está tratado. A exceção que me refiro é por exemplo não conseguiu fazer o post na URL.

Comment: Poste o seu código completo javascript e o backend completo por favor.

Comment: Mesmo quando dá alguma exceção ele entra naquela função?

Comment: Virgilio, postado.

Comment: jbueno, exatamente isso que eu quero. Saber q ele não conseguiu entrar na função do backend.

Comment: Então, você que tratar as *exceptions*, não é? O que eu quero saber é se mesmo quando estoura alguma exception no server side a função do client-side está sendo executada. Porque se for isso, tem mais algo errado.

Comment: @jbueno, o server já está com o tratamento para não estourar exceptions.
A única exception que poderia estourar neste caso aí é se o post não conseguisse acessar a URL. ou seja, alguma exceção na tentativa de post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação do [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), existe o `.fail()`. Utilize ele para fazer algo caso acontece algum erro no server.

Um exemplo simples seria este:

```js
$.post("MinhaUrl/AsyncMessage", function() {
  console.log("sucesso");
}).done(function() {
  console.log("segundo sucesso");
}).fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
}).always(function() {
  console.log("terminou");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```